# Geth Reverse Proxy "Invalid Host Specified"

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc

I am getting 403 "invalid host specified"

Running geth this way:

```
docker run --rm -p 8547:8547 -p 30303:30303 --name=geth -dti -v /data/geth:/data ethereum-node --datadir=/data --http --http.addr="0.0.0.0" --http.port="8547" --calaveras --http.api="eth,debug" --http.corsdomain="*"
```

My nginx is setup this way:

```
server {
        root /var/www/website.com;

        index index.html;

        server_name website.com;
        error_page 404 = /404.html;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location /rpc {
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                proxy_pass    http://127.0.0.1:8547/;
        }

        location /404.html {
                internal;
        }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Connecting to Web3 this way:

```
const web3 = new Web3('https://website.com/rpc);
```

What else can I try?

Answer (score 0):

```
server {
        root /var/www/website.com;

        index index.html;

        server_name website.com;
        error_page 404 = /404.html;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location /rpc {
                proxy_pass    http://127.0.0.1:8547/;
        }

        location /404.html {
                internal;
        }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
}
```